# ButtonX.Visible = false; Hangs the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

Asp.Net C# web application
I have a `Button X`,
On the Server side C#  `(ButtonX.Visible = false;)` Button goes away (good), but on the next post the page never renders. I debugged all works fine, debugger returns control, but the page never renders. If I comment out the
 `(ButtonX.Visible = false;)` all works fine, except for the `buttonX` being visible in the Browser

Whats up with that? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: ButtonX? Did you ask Wolverine? :)

Comment: What does "Hangs the browser" mean? Have you looked at the html source, is it really empty?

Comment: Have you tried running it without the debugger attached?

Comment: Are you aware that `ButtonX.Visible = false` on server side means that button will never render client side? Do you have some client side code that looks for it, that may be hanging when it isn't there?

Comment: Recursive event handler perhaps?

Comment: Hang the browser = busy never stops, I would like the Button to go away. No Client side script looking for it.

Comment: <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" 
            Text="Look for more information?" Visible="False" /> Server Side if (theresMore == true)
            {
                Button2.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Button2.Visible = false;
                TextBox7.Text = null;
            }

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide button in client side. do not make `ButtonX.Visible = false`  as @southshoreAK suggests, rather in javascript make it hide or show:-

```
document.getElementById('<%=ButtonX.ClientID%>').style.visibility = 'visible';//to show

document.getElementById('<%=ButtonX.ClientID%>').style.visibility = 'hidden';//to hide
```